# to arrange a data set based on multiple criteria in a different sheet

Tags: criteria, sumproduct

looking for a vba code to arrange the data set available "consolidate_data" sheet to an output sheet "outbudget" using the different criteria available in the "outbudget" sheet.

I have tried to perform the needed via excel formula using "sumproduct" and it worked well, however i would like to convert the same into a VBA code.

the vba code first needs to extract the mission count and codes from the consolidated_data sheet, eliminate the duplicates the past the same in the output sheet "outbudget" in the first column.

then accordingly, the vba code needs to compute the ranges according to the criteria in the "outbudget" sheet.

Comment: how is it possible to attach the workbook i am working on, as it will ease the explanation of what is needed ?!